# Does angularjs impact seo?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, seo

I was developing a website with angular JS. Now I'm in the middle of it. Suddenly got a question if this affects Search engine crawlers?

Looking for a solution.

Comment: If implemented with html5 mode, proper rewrite to index.html, and the inclusion of a sitemap, your seo will be just fine. sitemap is optional, but it would be a good idea to include it anyway.

Comment: Thanks kevin. Its implemented in html5 mode. I will also include the sitemap.

Comment: Well I have HTML5 implemented with pushstate, google robot still see empty site. So my answer is no, google still can't handle angularjs sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as we know as of today only [Google can handle content powered by JavaScript](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2014/05/understanding-web-pages-better.html). So this *shouldn't* hurt your SEO efforts with Google but will hurt you with all of the other search engines.

Comment: I just read the same article John. But does other search engines also does similar implementation like google?

Comment: I still see empty site in google webdeveloper tools.